# .NET Programming and interfacing with a USB device

Tags: .net, usb

This question about my latest interest -  Scalextric (Slot Cars).

I'm going to build my own track by way of some MDF and copper tape.

What I would also like to do is develop a lap counter to run on my PC using some sort of usb attached sensor, maybe a light sensor or something to send a current to my application when a car passes over the sensor.

So my question is, can anyone recommend where I should start, would I need a custom circuit board for example? Can I directly interface with a usb sensor from a .Net app? Any help would be grately appreciated.

I'd post the final solution as an open source project too. Just to note, I want to build this application myself, there is an off the shelf program that would do the job but I want to learn.

Comment: Maybe something like these http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?category=2

Comment: Thanks @kenny, phidgets looks more like what i need.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into [Netduino](http://www.netduino.com/)? It's an open source hardware platform programmed with the .NET Micro Framework. Not had any experience of it myself, past reading about it, but it looks like it could fit the bill.

Some more information about communicating with the board over USB here: [Windows Application Communicating with Netduino Over USB](http://blog.mark-stevens.co.uk/?p=196)

More basic info here: [Netduino, a .NET-powered open source electronics platform](http://blog.makezine.com/archive/2010/08/new-in-the-maker-shed-netduino-a-ne.html)

Also take a look over on [electronics.stackexchange.com](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=netduino)

Comment: Thanks for this Ira, i've had a look and it would definitely get me started with board programming. I think i might see how far i get with phidgets though.